# Weird behavior with Excel Pivot, Help Needed

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

I am facing a really weird issue with my Excel Pivot. As can be seen in the attached screen shot when I am selecting individual months in my pivot table filter I am getting the required data for each month.

But once I select more than one month in my pivot table filter, I am getting a different behavior for my column values.
**Forecast Column** - Although aggregating but not giving the correct result.
**Actual Column** - Only displaying results for the latest month (in this case Nov 17).

Any help or suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Tools Used:

1. MS SQL Server 2012
2. SSAS 2012
3. Microsoft Office 365

Regards,
Saif.

[image: Excel Pivot Screenshot]

Comment: Have you access to the cube? It could be that the aggregation is not the default one, for example could be Last Not Empty.